# how to add a custom value in grafana legend?

Tags: grafana, prometheus

There is a graph display elasticsearch index count, see below
[image]

I want to add a value: diff = max - min in `Legend`, how to implement it?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

I'm pretty sure you can't, easily. You can hack your way around it by adding yet another query to your graph, something like

```
max_over_time(my_metric[[[__range_s]]s]) - min_over_time(my_metric[[[__range_s]]s])
```

Grafana [will replace](https://grafana.com/docs/reference/templating/#the-range-variable) the `[[__range_s]]` bit with the length of the time range of the current dashboard, e.g. `3600` for the default `1h`, so the query actually sent to Prometheus will be

```
max_over_time(my_metric[3600s]) - min_over_time(my_metric[3600s])
```

Meaning Prometheus will compute the difference between the max and min separately from Grafana (which does it on top of the samples returned by Prometheus). (It will also compute this difference for the whole time range, not just the most recent sample, which is what you're interested in.) Then you can tweak the display of said time series in Grafana (e.g. by setting line=0, fill=0) so it will not show up on the graph itself, only in the legend. But the legend will then display the current value of the difference, as well as its min, max, avg, which will be quite the crappy UX.

**Edit:** Or you can add said query to a separate panel (e.g. a table panel), to the right of your graph. That may let you better control the UX, although it still won't be part of the actual legend.

**Edit 2:** One final thing you could try, that would give you exactly what you want, is to tweak Grafana's graph panel to add a "range" value next to "min", "max" and the bunch. The source code is [here](https://github.com/grafana/grafana/tree/master/public/app/plugins/panel/graph), I'm pretty sure it's mostly a copy-pasta job. You likely wouldn't even have to rebuild all of Grafana, you could just package the modified panel as "Tweaked Graph Panel" plugin and drop it into your Grafana deployment's plugins folder. Then, in your dashboard, instead of using "Graph Panel", use "Tweaked Graph Panel".